# How can I safely execute SQL statements in parallel in an ActiveRecord migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mariadb

I'm writing an ActiveRecord migration which affects every row in nearly every table in my >1 TB MariaDB database. The migration logic is structured such that each table (and probably each individual row) could theoretically be operated on independently of the changes being made to any other table/row, ie I am generating hundreds of `Update table Set column = function_of(column)` statements. Which columns I modify is dependent on runtime data so they are generated at the beginning of the migration.

The issue I have is that after I generate the hundreds of `Update` statements, I don't want to execute them in serial because it will take dozens of hours and cause downtime for my production application. Each individual per-table `Update` statement takes about 15 minutes in the worst case, which is short enough to squeeze through I think, but ActiveRecord doesn't seem to have an obvious way to execute the statement in parallel. I've seen vague yet ominous messages in other StackOverflow posts that just doing `Thread.new { execute '<query>' }` is unsafe, but I am not sure why.

Is there a safe way to accomplish my goal? If not, why specifically is this not possible in an ActiveRecord migration?

Comment: Please define the vague and ominous messages that say doing multi-threaded queries is unsafe, because all ActiveRecord is doing is saying "hey database server, please run this query and report back." If it's unsafe then it's not because ActiveRecord is unsafe, it's because the database server says it's unsafe. If your question is "why is __ unsafe?" then please define __ very clearly.